# how to add a compiler type supported for sccache?

Tags: c, compilation, ccache

i use a complier of greenhills(ccv850.exe), a gcc-like complier.
i want to use sccache to fasten my build .
but it seems sccache not support it.

can you kindly give me some help?
thanks!

attention: I use sccache, not the ccache.
(i cannot create a new tag doe sccache)

the detail error as follow:

```
D:\CX\SW\ccachetest>sccache ccv850.exe -filetype.c main2.c -c main2.o

[2024-03-24T14:46:09Z DEBUG sccache::config] Attempting to read config file at "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\sccache\config\config"

[2024-03-24T14:46:09Z DEBUG sccache::config] Couldn't open config file: failed to open file C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\sccache\config\config

[2024-03-24T14:46:10Z DEBUG sccache::commands] Server sent UnsupportedCompiler: ""

sccache: error: failed to execute compile

sccache: caused by: Compiler not supported:
```